# How to sort a generic sequence with pinned elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting

I have a sequence of numbers and I need to sort them, except from some numbers that should stay pinned in their initial position. For example
lets say that my sequence is:

```
33, 20, 48, 17, 48, 36, 20, 12, 25
```

...and the numbers 20 and 25 should stay pinned. Then after sorting the sequence, I should get the result below:

```
12, 20, 17, 33, 36, 48, 20, 48, 25
```

How could I implement this kind of restricted sorting? The method I want to implement has this signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, bool> pinPredicate)
{
    //...
}
```

This method could then be used to produce the desirable result like this:

```
var source = new int[] { 33, 20, 48, 17, 48, 36, 20, 12, 25 };
var result = source.OrderBy(n => n, n => n == 20 || n == 25);
```

My straightforward attempts to solve this problem chaining the LINQ methods [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) and [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) have failed. The problem seems too complex to be solved using a single chain of LINQ methods.

Comment: Are they pinned because of their **value** or because of their **index**?

Comment: The simplest solution is likely going to be effectively 'remove' the values you don't want to sort, then insert them back in after the sorting is done.

Comment: @mjwills by their value. But I could also use a solution that accepts a list of indices.

Comment: Does "pinned" mean that the elements having the specified values will remain in exactly the same place, i.e. at the same index? If so, I agree with @mjwills comment. You'll need to make a new array to be sorted, without the "pinned" elements, sort that, then merge the "pinned" ones back in by index into a collection of the original length. That said, as you well know, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. **What have you tried? What did that code do? How was that different from what you wanted? What _specifically_ do you need help with?**

Comment: `by their value.` Then my `simplest solution` approach is what I'd suggest. Use the `Select` overload which includes indices. `ToList` them and store them somewhere. `Where` them out of the original list, and `OrderBy` then `ToList` to sort everything else. Then `Insert` them back in (left to right).

Comment: @mjwills I like your idea! I am concerned a bit about the performance of this solution, because my sequence of numbers is quite large (~1,000,000).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I asked if anyone knows any third-party library that offers this functionality, or alternatively for ideas about how could I implement it myself. I haven't try much already, because it would be a waste of time if there is an open source implementation out there.

Comment: Asking for third-party libraries is off-topic. Asking for "ideas about how could I implement it myself" is too broad. People are expected to do sufficient research and make a significant enough attempt to actually _solve_ their own problem first, to keep their questions on-topic and specific enough to be appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you are right that asking for libraries is of-topic. But why is too broad to ask for ideas about solving this problem? According to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it seems that my question is a good fit for StackOverflow. It is *a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.* Feel free to edit my question if you think that it can be improved somehow, so that I can learn by example.

Comment: _"why is too broad to ask for ideas"_ -- because there can be a large number of different ideas, any one of which _could_ be an answer to the question. That is literally _too broad_. If a person cannot predict ahead of time which of many different answers will actually be the answer you would accept as _the_ answer, then your question is too broad.

Comment: Frankly, the one posted answer is clear proof of this point. Two different algorithms were provided, and yet neither has yet been accepted by you as the answer. Instead, a new dialogue has begun, as the author of that question works to try to figure out **what is it exactly you actually want**? Again, this is the very definition of _too broad_. You are demonstrating through your own actions exactly why your question is _too broad_.

Comment: I thought I was reasonably clear: the question needs to show some effort to implement this yourself. Feel free to use suggestions already provided in the comments. Provide a [mcve], explain what that code does, in what way that attempt does not meet your goal, and what _specifically_ you need help with improving.

Comment: Frankly, your question may not be salvageable. Once you head down the wrong road, often you leave so much mud in your tracks that there's no cleaning things up. IMHO the appropriate thing to do would be to delete this question, and _maybe_ post a new one using the information you've gleaned to produce **your** best effort. I.e. you've seen some proposed solutions, they don't work for you, so produce _another_ solution on your own that improves on those. If it's good enough, great. You're done. No new question needed. If it's not, now you have a way to post a good question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho my last 3 comments have been deleted. Did you deleted them? And if so, why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200895/discussion-between-theodor-zoulias-and-peter-duniho).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this LINQ solution.

```
private static IEnumerable<int> PinnedSort(IEnumerable<int> numbers, ISet<int> pinnedNumbers)
{
    // Extract pinned numbers into (number, index) tuples
    // Might be cleaner to make a class here instead
    var onlyPinnedNumbers = numbers
        .Select((number, index) => (number, index))
        .Where(pair => pinnedNumbers.Contains(pair.number));

    // Sort other numbers that don't exist in pinned numbers set
    var sortedNumbers = numbers
        .Where(number => !pinnedNumbers.Contains(number))
        .OrderBy(number => number)
        .ToList();

    // Insert pinned numbers into sorted list
    foreach (var (number, index) in onlyPinnedNumbers)
    {
        sortedNumbers.Insert(index, number);
    }

    return sortedNumbers;
}
```

Which can be run like this:

```
var numbers = new int[] { 33, 20, 48, 17, 48, 36, 20, 12, 25 };

// Store pinned numbers in hashset, for O(1) lookups
var pinnedNumbers = new HashSet<int> { 20, 25 };

var pinnedSort = PinnedSort(numbers, pinnedNumbers);

Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", pinnedSort) + " }");
```

**Output:**

```
{ 12, 20, 17, 33, 36, 48, 20, 48, 25 }
```